# Blogs to follow to further learning

Tags: learning

> I've tried my best to keep this question non-subjective so am not asking which blogs are definitively "the BEST" but instead am using the opportunity to just try to broaden my scope of reading around the subject.

I am already reading blogs by Michael Bolton, James Bach, Alan Richardson, Dorothy Graham, the Google Testing blog (James Whittaker) and the Weekend Testing blog.

> Can anyone make some further recommendations?

Comment: Sounds like a prime candidate for Community Wiki :)

Comment: How would I go about setting that up ?

Comment: If you edit the post, you should see a checkbox for "Community Wiki" near the bottom. Essentially, it gives a clear indicator to others that "This isn't an 'answerable' question, but is one that will still be very useful to the community."

Comment: Edit: hmm, I went to one of my questions. It looks like the CW link is gone. Awkward...

Comment: So, according to meta, only answers can be made CW now. Interesting. Moderators can still make questions CW, but I wouldn't say it's worth a flag :)

Comment: This would be a *whole lot more useful* if you could pick a specific topic. This seems to have collected a bunch of barely-related links to blogs (or, in a few cases, links to links to blogs, and in one or two instances, links to things that weren't blogs at all). Someone looking for information will generally have at least some idea of what they want: testing methodology, test design, automation, management, etc. - throwing an ever-longer reading list at them is *less helpful than it should be*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://feeds.softwaretestingclub.com/ is the official area we aggregate Software Testing Blogs and other sources.  In the footer you can subscribe to separate topics by RSS (Blogs, Spanish, Events, Jobs, etc).  Latest posts from the Blog section also appear on our main website and blog.

I've lost track on how many blogs are listed, it is a lot and is constantly updated.

Comment: This is the aggregation I rely on the most.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest:

1. http://angryweasel.com/blog/
2. http://www.testingmentor.com/imtesty/
3. http://testapprentice.com/
4. http://testing.gershon.info/

Comment: The domain testingmentor is for sale, so 2nd link is outdated.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a list of blogs (from my blog).

http://strazzere.blogspot.com/p/people-in-testing.html

Lots of good ones in there...

Comment: Wow this is extensive ... Thanks! I actually just came across your blog this afternoon Joe but didn't find that particular post.

Comment: Thanks.  In the blogspot paradigm, that's a "page" and not a "post".  You can see a list of pages ("Home" "About This Blog" "25 Things About Me" "People in Testing" "Friends") in a horizontal navigation bar in the top portion of each page.

Comment: I've recently added a new Page I call "What People are Writing" which aggregates links to blogs I like. You can find it here: http://strazzerej.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not a comprehensive list, but, here's some of my favourites, not including the ones that you've already mentioned.

[Software Testing Club](http://softwaretestingclub.com) - Not just blogs, but, a great source of information, and does aggregate many testing blogs.

[Evil Tester](http://www.eviltester.com)

[RBCS blog](http://www.rbcs-us.com/blog)

[Tester Tested!](http://testertested.blogspot.com) - Pradeep Soundararajan's blog

[Testy Testy](http://blog.testyredhead.com) - Lanette Creamer's blog

[The social tester](http://thesocialtester.posterous.com/)

Comment: +1 for software testing club, everyone should also look at their publication 'Testing Planet' for some great articles http://www.thetestingplanet.com/ (am currently writing my first article for them)

Answer (score 4):

I'd also add:

http://www.sqaforums.com

http://blog.isthereaproblemhere.com

http://www.questioningsoftware.com

http://blogs.msdn.com

http://www.practicalqa.com

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't yet, follow these guys. These are the guys that everyone else in the other mentioned blogs are following.

Michael Bolton: http://www.developsense.com/blog/
James Bach: http://www.satisfice.com/blog/

Comment: Good suggestions if this does become a community wiki but just as a side note these were the first 2 blogs I actually mentioned in my question ;)

Comment: aww yes good shout :)

Comment: This one is gold: mrslavchev.com.

Answer (score 4):

Being a simple person, I just subscribed to Rosie Sherry's http://www.google.com/reader/shared/user/01950759537487304585/label/softwaretesters in my google reader and get a lots of great software testing blogs in one subscription.

Comment: Thanks :)  This is actually the main Blog STC Testing Feeds, which is in turn re-used across STC.  The best one to subscribe to that is always updated.  Just added some more today actually :)  Now the bloggers just need to keep blogging.

Answer (score 3):

Would also like to add...

http://blog.utest.com/

http://www.testinggeek.com/

http://www.testingminded.com/2010/04/top-100-software-testing-blogs.html

http://www.buzzle.com/articles/software-testing-tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm big into aggregated "planets" and I think [Test Automation Planet](http://tap.szabgab.com/) is great.

Many of the blogs listed above are also aggregated into this single RSS feed.

Answer (score 2):

I like the [Google Testing Blog](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default), it includes some great stuff from James Whittaker who used to be a head honcho of Test at Microsoft, and not so long ago moved to Google to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

For those of us who speaks Hebrew-
[israeltestblog](http://www.tapuz.co.il/blog/userBlog.asp?FolderName=israeltestblog)