# Software testing and QA podcasts

Tags: learning

In a similar vein to the question [blogs to follow to further learning](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/336/blogs-to-follow-to-further-learning), I would like to ask if there are any noteworthy testing podcasts? Searching in iTunes domes up pretty empty on the topic.

I know there are heaps of development ones, are there any good testing podcasts?

*Note: This would be community wiki, but the feature on questions appears to have been removed.*

Comment: Since I asked this question, I have started my own ... Testcast  @ www.testcast.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [testingpodcast.com](http://testingpodcast.com)

They have over 200 quality software testing podcasts listed as of May, 2011.  Series with more than 20 podcasts include Matthew Heusser's excellent "TWIST" (This Week in Software Testing), StickyMinds, Watir podcasts, Indianapolis Workshops on Software Testing, and RBCS.

Categories

- ATI Podcasts (3)
- DevelopSense (1)
- Indianapolis Workshops on Software Testing (21)
- InfoQ (2)
- James Bach’s Blog (2)
- MichaelDKelly.com Media (6)
- Misc (6)
- Panamo QA (15)
- RBCS Podcast (24)
- Software Quality and Testing Podcasts (18)
- StickyMinds.com Podcasts (85)
- Testing Stories from India (6)
- This Week In Software Testing (49)
- TWiST-Plus (3)
- Watir Podcast (44)

Comment: I did find the explanations you provided insightful and cogent.

Answer (score 6):

I'll second Taruns answer of google video & CodingQA - the CodingQA guys are a really likeable duo just putting their ideas across. they don't claim to be experts, just imparting knowledge on how they operate & their understanding of testing methodologies.

I find itunes proves more fruitful if you search for actual topics, as opposed to high level subject areas.

My search for "agile testing" & "software testing" turned up limited results, but when I searched for things like "exploratory testing", "james bach", "Cem Kaner", "James Whittaker" I had better luck.

I try to search for podcasts which will answer a question I'm currently rolling around in my head - for example, I'm currently learning about exploratory testing & after searching around google I now have a range of buzzwords (see above) which I search for in itunes.

Answer (score 3):

May be this - http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/google-videos-cem-kaner/id212658036

Check this also - http://www.codingqa.com/

Comment: That google video link goes to an empty show.

Comment: No it does not, I checked it again. Do you get 404? Can you try http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ to check if it down only for you?

Comment: No the link works, but there are zero shows, you follow the link on the page and then it goes to a 404 on http://www.satisfice.com/moodle/

Answer (score 3):

On se-radio.net there are some episode on testing.

http://www.se-radio.net/2007/10/episode-70-gerard-meszaros-on-xunit-test-patterns/

http://www.se-radio.net/2010/02/episode-155-johannes-link-lasse-koskela-on-tdd/

http://www.se-radio.net/2010/06/episode-164-agile-testing-with-lisa-crispin/

http://www.se-radio.net/2010/09/episode-167-the-history-of-junit-and-the-future-of-testing-with-kent-beck/

If you don't mind the german accent of the interviewer there is some realy valuable information in there. Some other episode metion it as wel just search the site.

Comment: They are mostly developer testing focused, I was hoping for something testing specific.

Answer (score 3):

I did a quick round up of podcasts and videos a few months back - http://blog.softwaretestingclub.com/2011/07/software-testing-podcasts-videos/

Answer (score 0):

This has been posted on Twitter by STC quite recently:

http://www.softwaretestingclub.com/video?sort=mostPopular

Answer (score 0):

This one features interviews with various testing experts:
https://joecolantonio.com/testtalks/.

Answer (score 0):

One of my favourite tech podcast is from AngieJones

[AngieJones.tech](http://angiejones.tech/featured/)

And quite cool Ministry of Testing

[MinistryofTesting Podcast](https://www.ministryoftesting.com/dojo/podcasts)